# Android Studio jTDS java.lang.NullPointerException java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I am trying to create an app where it connects to a Microsoft SQL Server and adds some data to just a single table (Vendor) but it keeps rejecting my connection to the server. I created a user and a password just for this db alone. I am working on a MacBook and the server is on another Windows PC but I don't think this is why it is not working. For the ip I used the IPv4 found when I write ipconfig in cmd.

This is the code:

```
public class connectClass {
    private Connection connection;

    public Connection connectClass(){
        String ip = "won't put it here for obvious reasons";
        String user = "android";
        String password = "android";
        String port = "1433";
        String database = "dbExemplu";
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try{
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            String sirUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + port + ";" + "databasename=" + database
                    + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sirUrl);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getException() + " " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn1;
    private EditText txtCode, txtName, txtPhone;
    private Vendor vendor;
    private Collections cols = new Collections();
    private Connection connection;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtCode = findViewById(R.id.codeVendor);
        txtName = findViewById(R.id.nameVendor);
        txtPhone = findViewById(R.id.phoneVendor);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.saveVendor);

        connectClass connect = new connectClass();
        connection = connect.connectClass();

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                vendor = new Vendor();
                vendor(txtCode.getText().toString());
                vendor.setName(txtName.getText().toString());
                vendor.setPhone(txtPhone.getText().toString());
                cols.vendors.add(vendor);
                addVendor(vendor.getCode().toString(), vendor.getName().toString(), vendor.getPhone().toString);
}
});

        void addVendor(String code, String name, String phone) {
        Statement st;
        String s;
        try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
            s = "insert into Furnizori values ('" + code + "'" + ",'" + name + "','" + phone + "')";
            st.executeUpdate(s);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My SQL Server authentication was set as Windows Authentication only and I had to set it as SQL Server Authentication.